# Magento 2 : Block Not Found Error

Tags: magento2, blocks, forms

I have a custom form with block that I want to load, but everytime I call the controller to load the form I always got this error=

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class
>   'Lime\Courier\Block\Adminhtml\Preferences\Edit' not found in
>   C:\xampp7\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php:93

I already make sure the block folder structure is right and first folder and file name start with capital letter, I also already delete var/generation folder and run setup:di:compile, but nothing works

here's my xml layout code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Lime\Courier\Block\Adminhtml\Preferences\Edit" name="lime_courier_preferences_edit"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

in Lime\Courier\Block\Adminhtml\Preferences\Edit directory I have Edit.php :

```
<?php
namespace Lime\Courier\Block\Adminhtml\Preferences\Edit;

class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
      die('a');
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize blog post edit block
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'preferences_id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'Lime_Courier';
        $this->_controller = 'lime_courier';

        parent::_construct();

        if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Lime_Courier::save')) {
            $this->buttonList->update('save', 'label', __('Save Courier Preferences'));
            $this->buttonList->add(
                'saveandcontinue',
                [
                    'label' => __('Save and Continue Edit'),
                    'class' => 'save',
                    'data_attribute' => [
                        'mage-init' => [
                            'button' => ['event' => 'saveAndContinueEdit', 'target' => '#edit_form'],
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
                -100
            );
        } else {
            $this->buttonList->remove('save');
        }

        if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Lime_Courier::preferences_delete')) {
            $this->buttonList->update('delete', 'label', __('Delete Preferences'));
        } else {
            $this->buttonList->remove('delete');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve text for header element depending on loaded post
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('lime_courier')->getId()) {
            return __("Edit Preferences '%1'", $this->escapeHtml($this->_coreRegistry->registry('lime_courier')->getTitle()));
        } else {
            return __('Lime Courier');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check permission for passed action
     *
     * @param string $resourceId
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowedAction($resourceId)
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($resourceId);
    }

    /**
     * Getter of url for "Save and Continue" button
     * tab_id will be replaced by desired by JS later
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getSaveAndContinueUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('courier/*/save', ['_current' => true, 'back' => 'edit', 'active_tab' => '']);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried my solution?

Comment: If it working please up vote my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Lime\Courier\Block\Adminhtml\Preferences\Edit" name="lime_courier_preferences_edit"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Lime\Courier\Block\Adminhtml\Preferences\Edit\Edit" name="lime_courier_preferences_edit"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

You missed a Class name from `xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Change you class namespace & remove last edit directory as your overridden file path is `Lime\Courier\Block\Adminhtml\Preferences\Edit` :

```
 namespace Lime\Courier\Block\Adminhtml\Preferences;

 class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container
 {
   ....
   ....
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `Edit` from your class namespace

`namespace Lime\Courier\Block\Adminhtml\Preferences\Edit`

to

`namespace Lime\Courier\Block\Adminhtml\Preferences`

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the namespace. Magento is trying to find Edit.php class in Lime\Courier\Block\Adminhtml\Preferences\Edit

Change the line

namespace Lime\Courier\Block\Adminhtml\Preferences\Edit;

to

namespace Lime\Courier\Block\Adminhtml\Preferences;